# Does Wordpress 4.9.6 (or 4.9) works with MySQL 5.20?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Does Wordpress 4.9.6 (or 4.9) works with MySQL 5.20? Is there a way to make a test somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Wordpress documentation the explanation follows,

To run WordPress we recommend your host supports:

```
MySQL version 5.6 or greater OR MariaDB version 10.0 or greater.
```

Note: If you are in a legacy environment where you only have older PHP or MySQL versions, WordPress also works with PHP 5.2.4+ and MySQL 5.0+, but these versions have reached official End Of Life and as such may expose your site to security vulnerabilities.

So, its better to upgrade your MySQL

Comment: Hi, that's the problem, the hosting where I intend to build a website have only MySQL 5.20.It's out of my reach to updated it, but its good to know. Thanks a lot for your answer!